# Не могу вывести список на c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, потоки-данных, stl

Не получается вывести список s, выходит ошибка

> main.cpp:23:47: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
> `copy (s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator(cout, " "));`

не могу понять в чем проблема, заранее благодарен

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, i, foo, bar;
    cout << "N= "; 
    cin >> a;
    list <int> s = {};
    cout << "Сколько элементов будет в массиве: "; 
    cin >> foo;
    bar=0;
    cout << "Вводите числа: ";
    for (i = 1; i <= foo; i++)
    {
        int massiv;
        cin >> massiv;
        s.push_front(massiv);
    }
    copy (s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явно укажите тип выводимых элементов:

```
copy (s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```